# Scheduling a dynamic asp.net function?

Tags: asp.net, scheduling

My web application is an SMS service that sends out SMS messages using an external library.

I would like to know if I can send a specific asp function using any scheduler method for asp.net?

Example would be like the web user is able to schedule a specific message to be sent everyday.

What I've found is mostly for scheduling specific webpages to run or process which is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start:

[Quartz.NET - Enterprise Job Scheduler for .NET Platform](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

> Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open
>   source job scheduling system that can
>   be used from smallest apps to large
>   scale enterprise systems.

[Combine Web and Windows Services to Run Your ASP.NET Code at Scheduled Intervals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163821.aspx)

Comment: I think that second link is a bad idea. Aside from using ASMX services (WCF should be used), it pretty much assumes a monolithic ASP.NET application that the developer is too dumb to refactor. Only if all the code is in the web app (so there is no separate data layer or business logic layer) would I consider calling into an ASP.NET application. Instead, make a separate service that the Windows Service can call.